# How to add #anchor at the end of the Wordpress URL if the traffic source is coming from Google search

Tags: wordpress, anchor, permalinks

I have Wordpress and I would like that all visitors who access my site by searching in google (traffic source), go directly to a specific part of the page (focus).

To focus on this part, I need to include the anchor at the end of the url: #welcome-source-google
https://example.com/category/page-or-post/#welcome-source-google

I think I need to insert this code, probably in functions.php:

```
function organic_source_anchor() {
  if (preg_match('/(www\\.)?google\\./', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $postID ) . '#welcome-source-google' );
    exit;
  }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'organic_source_anchor' );
```

I got this code by researching, but since I am not a programmer, I believe there are several errors or maybe I need to put the code out of functions.
A problem that happens is that I didn’t want to disable the cache, as this frame appears to all visitors, but if the source is from google, I wanted the focus on the part this page.

Comment: Is it not possible to just get the URL of the current page and if the source is from google add the anchor?
example: wordpress link: site.com/category/post-name-date#anchor

Only add #anchor in all links.

Thank you!